# JS remoting question

Tags: javascript, integration, javascript-remoting, jquery, ajax

I am a newbie to SF. We have a spring MVC application. The controller returns the result as JSON object. My task is to call that controller method using  JS remoting and display the results in VisualForce page. Is it possible to do that? The spring application and SF are using SSO which is done using CAS server. The SF user is already authenticated by CAS server on the initial login. 
I see a lot of examples of JS remoting for ApexControllers, but can we do the same for a controller in a in Spring MVC application? If anybody can point me to an example that will be great. I am not supposed to use webservice/SOAP, as the spring webapp will not expose the service as webservice.

Thanks,
MK2013

Answer (score 2):

I don't think it's possible the way you ask it (also I'm not sure I got your question correctly). Javascript remoting is meant as a way to essentially call methods / data sources exposed from within Apex. To retrieve data from somewhere else with it probably means violating of "same domain" policy = your browser will block you. If it's client-side it will be guarded by your own browser, SSO will not have anything to do with it.

If you can't expose SOAP webservices in your Spring app, maybe you could make a chain of Javascript -> (remoting / standard AJAX toolkit) -> Apex -> ([REST callout](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_methods_system_restrequest.htm)) -> your Spring app? How does the Spring application expose the data?

Comment: Yes, if the spring page shows JSON data it can easily be gotten through a httprequest in apex called with Remote JS.

Comment: Or possibly something like CORS, but without Spring exposing the service it still seems like that will be a task in futility.